# get epoch time from span

Tags: javascript, html

the epoch converter work done but when i get the value of span by id and copy it to the broser give me undefined

```
<span name ="EpochClock" id="EpochClock"></span>
</div>
<input type="button" onClick="pprint()" value="print" >

    <script language="JavaScript">
      function pprint(){
        // If you want to use element Id
          var a = document.getElementById('EpochClock').value;
          document.write(a);
        // If you want to access by element name
          var b = document.getElementsByName('EpochClock')[0].value;
          document.write(b);
     }
     </script>
```

any help

Comment: Use innerHTML or innerText instead of value

Comment: the span has no property value, this is for form elements..

Comment: You can use the following instead `var b = document.querySelectorAll('span[name="EpochClock"]')[0].innerText;`